# How to correctly include jquery-ui effects on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I've been trying to include the jquery ui effects (more specifically the shake effect) on my wordpress theme. So far, I've only been able to include the jQuery script, but I really have no clue where to place the ui scripts and how to enqueue them.

This is the code I have. It obviously doesnt work:

```
    <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#manita-imagen").mouseover(function(){
            //$j(this).animate({ opacity: "hide" })
            // alert('asd');
            $j(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);
        });
    });

 </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't answer your question (hence comment), but you might be able to find Wordpress-specific help on the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'll add this question there as well, thanks!

Comment: no problem at all, I'm just sorry I couldn't be more helpful =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be possible that the jquery-ui-core included with wordpress does not include Effects. The documentation is unclear(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress) You might have to load a custom jquery-ui package from a url. Below will load full jquery UI from google cdn

`<?php wp_enqueue_script("myUi","https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"); ?>`

You can also use the  wp_enqueue_script($name, $src) function to load your own scripts.

Comment: It definitely does not include Effects: ["jQuery UI Effects is NOT included with the jquery-ui-core"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Notes)