# jQuery and Easing Conflict - jQuery and jQuery UI Load Issue but I can't Find It

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ok so typically you get this error when there is a jQuery conflict.  It's very common when two instances of jQuery are loaded or else jQuery UI is loading before jQuery.  But on my site, all the jQuery loads seem to be fine.  I'm at a loss as to what the problem is and I'm not sure where to turn next.  Does anyone have any idea?

TypeError: x.easing[this.easing] is not a function | in jquery.min.js

On this webpage: [http://a1.nbksite.com/](http://a1.nbksite.com)

**Please, consider.**

Comment: looks like you are missing the easing ui libraries

Comment: download the files from the effects section of jQuery UI and try

Comment: Ok I'll look into that. I didn't realize the easing libraries were separate packages. Have they always been separate? I never ran into this before.

Comment: Found this relevant thread after you pointed out the issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729685/how-to-correctly-include-jquery-ui-effects-on-wordpress

Comment: I don't know why you are including separate files... combine all the UI files into one and include it

Comment: Thanks Arun.  Yeah it's not my fault.  One of the stupid plugins is individually including them.  And that had me seriously confused.  After you commented about the effects library and I found the other thread, now everything makes sense.  Thanks for pointing out these goofy things.

Comment: Turns out it's not a plugin to blame.  It's WordPress itself!! See my final answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Arun thanks for the help. I failed to realize that the cores are custom built and I was wrong to assume the WP version of jQuery UI core included effects.

Found this relevant thread after you pointed out the issue:  [How to correctly include jquery-ui effects on wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729685/how-to-correctly-include-jquery-ui-effects-on-wordpress)

So here's the quick fix I use initially in functions.php:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.0', true );
```

But the above code is considered a "hack". According to WordPress docs, the proper thing to do is include each individual library because they are packaged with WordPress
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

So you're supposed to do this:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-effects-core");
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-effects-bounce");
```

I tested that and it works perfectly as long as wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui") has been previously called.  And then they expect you to also enqueue each individual library separately!!!

Frankly, I think this is appalling.  For the most part WordPress is elegant, but sometimes it falls flat on its face. Why in the world you would ever want to soak up server resources and slow down loading by using a bunch of individual  libraries is beyond me.  I can't believe the WP team thought this was a good idea.  The BEST thing to do in my opinion is this:

call wp_deregister_script on ALL the individual stupid scripts being loaded by WP and various plugins to STOP them from being loaded.

Then call wp_enqueue_script on a custom built jquery-ui core file that contains exactly what you want to use -- in this case a ui core that includes effects library.  The quick fix is to go ahead and just load jquery-ui.js from the jquery.com CDN.  In any case, it makes no sense to me that WordPress finds it logical to load a ton of separate libraries.

Final code for removing a ton of individual libraries loaded by WP plugins and replacing them all with custom jQuery UI.  Greatly reduces resources and increases page load speed:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );

wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-widget');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-mouse');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-resizable');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-button');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-draggable');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-position');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-sortable');

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.0', false );
```

Comment: but this renders a performance problem for the site as you have too many script files in the page

Comment: I made several edits as it wasn't written clearly.  Read it again.  My point is that WP renders a performance problem.  Blame them!  My answer tells how to fix it.

Comment: but at the end of the day it is your site which has the problem.. not WP's

Comment: um. what?  Do you fail to understand that my site has the problem because WP recommends doing it exactly the way the plugin on my site did? I'm not following your logic here. Future people who read this question or have a similar problem need to recognize that WP's philosophy is ill-designed so that they can do the right thing on their own WP sites.

Comment: whatever you say boss... what I meant was the end result of the approach and the performance problem associated with it... as a client I'm worried about the results in this case a website and its performance... read https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt